# Zurb Foundation base font size?

Tags: css, wordpress, zurb-foundation-5

I noticed the `<p>` are 1rem and very leaded out. I've tried overriding this, by up to and including `p {font-size: 14px !important}`

No affect.

I am using the compiled Foundation 5 CSS and JS, enqueued in a Wordpress theme. All else works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of this code snippet

```
p {font-size: 14px !important}
```

is definitely the right solution in general. What's more, this one

```
p {font-size: 14px}
```

should work well too. Here you are a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/Akarienta/pen/xbXmJw) (I have used `30px` just to briefly demonstrate it's working).

If this isn't working in your project it is probably because of order of you CSS includes - compiled Foundation CSS should always come first and your own style after that.

Comment: The order of the CSS files were reversed. This being Wordpress, it wasn't immediately apparent